# Android: Failure delivering result ResultInfo. What is wrong?

Tags: android

I have problem with mym app. Some code, which creates error:

```
        String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
            + " like'%" + name + "%'";
    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,
            selection, null, null);
```

and here is my error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=4321, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity 
...
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "m": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT data1 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND (display_name like'%I'm in a pool%')
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "m": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT data1 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype = 'vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2') AND (display_name like'%I'm in a pool%')
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:158)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.bulkQueryInternal(ContentProviderNative.java:330)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:245)`

Aneone know what is wrong?

Comment: Do you literally ask questions every 5 minutes then delete? Put in an honest attempt before asking for help!

Comment: do it like a man... With parameters `?` in selection(where query)and fill selectionArgs with them(parameters)

Answer (score 0):

`AND (display_name like'%I'm in a pool%')`

You've got an unescaped quote here in the middle of `I'm`. That's why your error is complaining about `SQLiteException: near "m": syntax error`

You need to escape your quotes before inserting them.